# I am trying to identify an smd 16 pin Linear Technology voltage regulator chip makes 5 volts with 6 volts dc in

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, identification, surface-mount

[image: photo]

I am trying to identify an smd 16 pin Linear Technology voltage regulator chip makes 5 volts with 6 volts dc in.

Comment: is it a linear or a switchmode regulator? What is *attached* to these pins? Could you make out that suppy and ground pins are?

Answer (score 2):

Oh wait. That was easy. It's an LT3433.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it to be this device: -

[image]

Image from here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3433f.pdf

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!